# Is there a checklist of action items that documents porting an Azure app from North America to China?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, servicebus, azureservicebus

I'm trying to deploy an Azure application that is currently working on Azure North America to Azure China. The service bus namespace has changed, for example, from servicebus.windows.net to servicebus.chinacloudapi.cn.

This results in numerous problems. [Geeks with blogs](http://geekswithblogs.net/shaunxu/archive/2013/06/10/tips-an-tricks-of-developing-on-windows-azure-china.aspx) addresses some of them.

However, even simple things like namespaceManager.QueueExists() fails with:

> uri provided  does not match service bus domain: servicebus.windows.net

This is when trying to reference WindowsAzure.ServiceBus.1.8.0.0

Is there a great list somewhere that gives all the changes that need to be made?

Comment: I haven't seen a comprehensive list outside of the blog you referred to.  we did have to upgrade the SDK to latest before providing the new endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the Azure services the following documents provide guidance for using Windows Azure in China: http://www.windowsazure.cn/zh-cn/develop/other/developerdifferences/

Comment: Here's the English version of this document: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn448523.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\Config`, you will find `servicebus.config`. You need to change the host names to use the ones for Azure China. Change the following:

`relayHostName` => `servicebus.chinacloudapi.cn`

`stsHostName` and `acmHostName` => `accesscontrol.chinacloudapi.cn`

That should fix the `QueueExists` issue. Let me know of any other issues!

Comment: This is an Azure VM. RDPing in tells me the framework is here: D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config. However, there is no servicebus.config file. Additionally, I need the setting to be deployable to North America as well as China without manual post-deployment server changes

Comment: Dude, your response worked, after I put the servicebus.config into the root of the worker role and set it to Copy Always. This allowed me to use v1.8 of the service bus and control the deployment somewhat. Alas, it's not an answer to my original question. On this specific issue, see also http://abhishekrlal.com/2011/03/22/clientsdkconfig/ and perhaps search for domain appfabriclabs, which falls into the same hole